# Splitting questions into difficulty categories

Tags: feature-request

Im not sure if this is possible because it seems like a difficult implementation. However its worth mentioning.

This site is meant for systems and networking professionals, which means if we are at this point we should have strengths, weaknesses, etc.

But there is also experience gaps. Ive been in IT for a year, so I am still new to alot of things, and my understanding of things is limited.This makes it hard to answer questions so I can build rep. Im sure everyone is proud of their rep and I would like to be able to build some up so I can use full features of the site. But alot of the questions I see come off as high level, and when I do see questions that I can actually answer, I usually get beat to it.

I wanna participate more and give back to the community if I can. This website is definitely beneficial, I just wish it was less abrasive, but thats a different story.

Maybe the mods or higher level members can sort questions out based on the difficulty. I can stick to a category and then as time goes on move up as I grow more experienced. It would help people with a high knowledge base stick to more relevant questions and people like myself who want to help but arent as knowledgeable to help as well.

Comment: From my perspective most of the questions we see are at entry/beginner level and below.

Comment: I don't see how it's easier / faster to tag a question you can instantly answer as "beginner level" than just... answering or duplicate voting it. So what's the incentive for the people with higher rep? Moderating for moderation's sake tends to burn people out.

Comment: Another issue is that you will have question askers mis-tagging a question's difficulty and/or taking offence at tags others apply, because they (obviously) found the question difficult enough that they needed to ask for help with it. I think for most people, it would be impossible to realistically judge the difficulty level of a question you don't actually know the answer to.

Comment: I see most of serverfaults audience as people who are too lazy to read even the first few pages of program documentation. Most of the answers are straight there in the FAQs. For some reason they prefer to spend an hour creating question here, instead of googling for 30 minutes. While answering here is pure fun to me, I'm not really sure it's helpful for people - *giving a person who wrote the accepted answer* an option to assign a difficultily class does seem an interesting idea - maybe it will help people to spend a little more time trying to solve it themselves before creating thread here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, the site is not designed to do this and if you want to propose a feature along that line, you would need to ask a question on the general [StackExchange meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) site. I could migrate this question over there, but this would almost certainly be rejected and I think there is a worthwhile discussion in this topic that is specific to Serverfault.

Personally, I don't think it's necessary at all (and I wouldn't be interested at all to triage questions into difficulty classes). You'll get your chance to contribute eventually and it's also OK to contribute another answer if you have something substantial to add that wasn't covered in earlier answers. Until then, the site is a great learning resource if you read a lot (highly voted) questions and answers as something will stick even if you don't need it immediately.

Also, you don't need to limit yourself to questions that you can answer immediately. You can (should?) also look for question in tags that interest you that you think you could tackle if you invest a little bit of time, thought and google-fu into it. If you select good questions (if only there were more of these ...), this is excellent training for your own problem solving skills. You just have to be prepared to learn that very often, the amount of rep you gain for an answer is inversely proportional to the difficulty of the question and the effort you have to put into an answer.

Comment: Ill do that Sven. Also I appreciate your thought out and respectful answer. I like feedback and advice when it doesn't come off as rude or condescending. ill try doing that and see how things work.